# The volume is preserved by the flow: where is the absolute value?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, classical-mechanics

Consider the following excerpt of the Liouville's theorem proof taken from "Arnold - mathematical methods of classical mechanics":
[image]

---

In changing the variables in the integral, I don't understand why there is not **the absolute value** of the Jacobian determinant. Why the determinant of the Jacobian of the flow is positive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $g^0$ is the identity, $g^t$ is a diffeomorphism, and $\det$ is continuous!

Comment: I came upon this question as I was looking for the answer to the question that the OP asked, but I am having a hard time understanding your answer. Could you explain to me in more details please?

Comment: @nan: The absolute value is needed when the diffeomorphism reverses orientation. But you have a continuous (smooth) family of diffeomorphisms joining $g^0$ and $g^t$; since $g^0$ is orientation-preserving, they must all be.

Comment: @TedShifrin I had the very same question. Luckily I came across this post. However there is something I still do not understand. Why do we have that $\det\partial g^{t}>0$ for all t? From what I know about continuous functions I can only conclude that $\det\partial g^{t}>0$ only in a nhd. of 0.

Comment: @Hans A continuous function on an interval cannot change sign without passing through $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the quick reply. I guess I missed the fact that $\det\partial g^{t}\neq 0$, since it is a diffeomorphism, right?

Comment: Yup, right. That’s it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't actually an absolute value in the change of variables formula. The absolute value only appears when you tweak the change of variables formula so that you flip the orientation of the region of integration whenever the Jacobian is negative.

Compare with ordinary one-dimensional definite integrals:

$$ \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(g(y)) g'(y) \, dy $$

As you can see, no absolute value: that's because the definite integral keeps track of the orientation of your interval.

If you instead think in terms of *unoriented* integrals, then you would need the absolute value:

$$ \int_{g([a,b])} f(x) \, dx = \int_{[a,b]} f(g(y)) |g'(y)| \, dy $$

to properly account for the possibility that $g(a) > g(b)$. (and this doesn't work at all if $g$ is not one-to-one on the domain $[a,b]$)

In higher dimensions, you have line integrals, surface integrals, and such which all *do* properly account for orientation, and thus you wouldn't need absolute values if you were using those.